# oracle - run stored procedure from script

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a script that I am using to build/drop tables and basically setting up the entire schema. 
After googling, I still can't figure out how to run a stored procedure.

The script is a .txt file, and I  run it using Apex SQL Oracle.

If I write only this line in a script:

```
execute procedurename(1); --where 1 is paramter.
```

> You have requested to run a script that does not contain any runnable
>   statements.

Comment: Is it a script or a stored procedure?  To run a script in sql*plus (not sure what Apex is), you'd preface it with `@`, e.g. `@c:\temp\your_script.txt`.

Comment: @Marc script is running fine. I just need that script o call the stored procedure. Does it make sense? Do you need more details?

Comment: The script should be able to call the stored proc with `call packagename.procname(1);`

Comment: @Marc what is packagename? how do i find out what's corresponding package name for my environment? or do I create a package from scratch for this task?

Comment: if your stored proc is not in a package, you don't need a package name.  Just `call procname(param);` should work.

Comment: @Marc It's saying unknown statement.

Comment: Is it a stored *procedure* or stored *function*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL>create or replace procedure procedurename(p_num number) 
as 
begin 
null; 
end;
/

Procedure created.

SQL>execute procedurename(1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

everything seems ok on SQLPLUS with oracle 11.

so it must be an apex thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since execute is a sqlplus statement ,try calling the procedure using begin-end PLSQL block in Apex SQL

```
BEGIN
procedurename(1); 
END;
/
```

save this in a file proc_call.sql  and then call it in your script like

```
 @C:\proc_call.sql
```

where C: is the sample path

For some information refer the below link

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=618393